# Where Dynamics CRM IsLogical attributes are stored?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to know where the IsLogical attributes are stored? for example:- if the user creates an image attribute, the system will create three attributes(imageId, Image Url, image timestamp); the image id is stored on the table but i don't know where the other attributes are stored;
[Image Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817886.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image information is stored in the `ImageDescriptor` table which you can access from the `FilteredImageDescriptor` view.

The filtered view contains the fields (among others):

- `imagedescriptorid` (the GUID linked from your source table)
- `imagetimestamp`
- `objectid`
- `objecttypecode` (source entity type code)
- `imageurl` (concatenated URL, relative to the CRM root)

However, if you use the filtered view of your custom entity (for example `Filterednew_mycustom`) which contains an image field, the filtered view will automatically bring in the fields:

- `entityimage`
- `entityimage_timestamp`
- `entityimage_url`
- `entityimageid`

Comment: Hi, sorry for being inconvenience, i also wants to know the purpose of relationship tables:-EntityRelationship,EntityRelationshipRelationships,EntityRelationshipRole,Relationship,RelationshipExtraCondition;  and what is the virtual attributes, where they are saved and its use and benefits. note:- i asked all of these questions as i am building metadata app similar to Dynamics CRM and Salesforce and i try to understand the internals of these apps.

Comment: Hi Jason. i am waiting your response

Comment: @yo2011 - Really this would be a separate question. I would make a new post so it gets a wider audience.